# Improved ACL editor for Windows file permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, access-control-list, file-permissions

I have recently been doing a lot of updates to our network drive permissions... such as consolidating direct user permissions into group permissions. The built-in ACL editor (Advanced Security Settings dialog) is adequate, but its limitations are frustrating, particularly that it cannot be resized and you cannot look at the list of existing entries at the same time as you are adding a new entry.

Is there an improved ACL editor that can be downloaded to supplement the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [SetACL Studio](http://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/). It was designed to be a replacement for Windows ACL Editor. It has an intuitive UI (resizeable, of course!) and is much more powerful than the original. It even has undo.

[I am the author of SetACL Studio]

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing large-scale changing of permissions, I'd suggest automating it with `icacls.exe` or the `get-acl` and `set-acl` PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: +1 The CLI is the one-true way.

Comment: get and set acls works very nicely just make sure you push and pop the permissions otherwise you'll lose your current acls.